# Is there a shell command to delay a buffer?

Tags: bash, shell

I am looking for a shell command X such as, when I execute:

```
command_a | X 5000 | command_b
```

the `stdout` of `command_a` is written in `stdin` of `command_b` (at least) 5 seconds later.

A kind of delaying buffer.

As far as I know, `buffer`/`mbuffer` can write at constant **rate** (a fixed number of bytes per second). Instead, I would like a constant **delay** in time (t=0 is when `X` read a `command_a` output chunk, at t=5000 it must write this chunk to `command_b`).

**[edit]** I've implemented it: https://github.com/rom1v/delay

Comment: Such a filter command would be fairly straight-forward to write, though non-trivial.  I'm not aware of any existing tool that does it.

Comment: Does the timing have to be exact, and what is the minimal accepted "chunk" of input? If I input byte 'A' at time 0, byte 'B' at time 0.7 and byte 'C' at time 1.9, does the output have to be timed exactly (5.0, 5.7 and 6.9 secs)? Or could ABC be output at 7.0 secs? What is the maximum size of the buffer - how many Mb of data should it delay before buffer is full?

Comment: Ideally, they should be timed nearly exactly (within 100ms for example, 4.9~5.1, 5.6~5.8, 6.8~7). The buffer size in bytes should be another parameter (`X -d 5000 -s 2m`).

Comment: What are you trying to solve by delaying the input? Maybe there's a better way of solving it.

Comment: I like your question. Somehow, it borders on realtime signal processing, like for audio. There is a lot to consider when timing becomes important. Did you look into signal processing / audio tools? For reliable timing, you will not be able to rely on a standard server-type system, since you can get long delays on I/O and other things happening. Moving from 'server thinking' to 'realtime thinking' is a (fun) challenge.

Comment: I'd love to see you set up [Jack Audio](http://jackaudio.org/), convert your data to floats and use Jack to send your data into a delay, then extract it and do a reverse conversion on the other side. On a decent system you could get the timing within 10-20 ms or so. Probably not what you're looking for, but fun to think about :) Plus, of course, you will get buffer overflow if your data comes in to quickly. Nvm, just throwing ideas out there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it seemed such a command dit not exist, I implemented it in C:
https://github.com/rom1v/delay

```
delay [-b <dtbufsize>] <delay>
```

Comment: You should call it something less generic. `catdelay`, `pipedelay`, `buffdelay`, `...`

Answer (score 8):

I know you said you're looking for a shell command, but what about using a subshell to your advantage? Something like:

```
command_a | (sleep 5; command_b)
```

So to `grep` a file `cat`-ed through (I know, I know, bad use of `cat`, but just an example):

```
cat filename | (sleep 5; grep pattern)
```

A more complete example:

```
$ cat testfile
The
quick
brown
fox
$ cat testfile | (sleep 5; grep brown)
# A 5-second sleep occurs here
brown
```

Or even, as Michale Kropat recommends, a group command with `sleep` would also work (and is arguably more correct). Like so:

```
$ cat testfile | { sleep 5; grep brown; }
```

Note: don't forget the semicolon after your command (here, the `grep brown`), as it is necessary!

Comment: This just provides a 5 second delay at the start.  If command_b is reading data faster than command_a is generating it, it will rapidly catch up, resulting in no delay for later output from command_a

Comment: @ChrisDodd Yeah that's true. There's definitely a distinction for non-trivial programs like the examples I gave.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
   read line 
   sleep 5
   echo $line
done
```

Save the file as "slowboy", then do

```
chmod +x slowboy
```

and run as

```
command_a | ./slowboy | command_b
```

Comment: You forgot to put the shebang.

Comment: Thank you plus some extra characters  :-)

Comment: This delays 5 seconds for each line.  If command_a is outputting lines  faster than one every 5 seconds, the delay will get longer and longer...

Answer (score 1):

This might work

```
time_buffered () {
   delay=$1
   while read line; do
       printf "%d %s\n" "$(date +%s)" "$line"
   done | while read ts line; do
       now=$(date +%s)
       if (( now - ts < delay)); then
           sleep $(( now - ts ))
       fi
       printf "%s\n" "$line"
   done
}

commandA | time_buffered 5 | commandB
```

The first loop tags each line of its input with a timestamp and immediately feeds it to the second loop. The second loop checks the timestamp of each line, and will sleep if necessary until `$delay` seconds after it was first read before outputting the line.

Comment: Yes, but I am looking for delaying a binary stream at a rate of several Mb/s. I consider coding it, but if it already exist, I would use it…

Answer (score 1):

Your question intrigued me, and I decided to come back and play with it. Here is a basic implementation in Perl. It's probably not portable (`ioctl`), tested on Linux only.

**The basic idea is:**

- read available input every X microseconds
- store each input chunk in a hash, with current timestamp as key
- also push current timestamp on a queue (array)
- lookup oldest timestamps on queue and write + discard data from the hash if delayed long enough
- repeat

**Max buffer size**

There is a max size for stored data. If reached, additional data will not be read until space becomes available after writing.

**Performance**

It is probably not fast enough for your requirements (several Mb/s). My max throughput was 639 Kb/s, see below.

**Testing**

```
# Measure max throughput:
$ pv < /dev/zero | ./buffer_delay.pl > /dev/null

# Interactive manual test, use two terminal windows:
$ mkfifo data_fifo
terminal-one $ cat > data_fifo
terminal-two $ ./buffer_delay.pl < data_fifo

# now type in terminal-one and see it appear delayed in terminal-two.
# It will be line-buffered because of the terminals, not a limitation 
# of buffer_delay.pl
```

**buffer_delay.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Select;
use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday usleep);
require 'sys/ioctl.ph';

$|++;

my $delay_usec = 3 * 1000000; # (3s) delay in microseconds
my $buffer_size_max = 10 * 1024 * 1024 ; # (10 Mb) max bytes our buffer is allowed to contain.
                              # When buffer is full, incoming data will not be read
                              # until space becomes available after writing
my $read_frequency = 10;      # Approximate read frequency in Hz (will not be exact)

my %buffer;                   # the data we are delaying, saved in chunks by timestamp
my @timestamps;               # keys to %buffer, used as a queue
my $buffer_size = 0;          # num bytes currently in %buffer, compare to $buffer_size_max

my $time_slice = 1000000 / $read_frequency; # microseconds, min time for each discrete read-step

my $sel = IO::Select->new([\*STDIN]);
my $overflow_unread = 0;      # Num bytes waiting when $buffer_size_max is reached

while (1) {
    my $now = sprintf "%d%06d", gettimeofday;  # timestamp, used to label incoming chunks

    # input available?
    if ($overflow_unread || $sel->can_read($time_slice / 1000000)) {

        # how much?
        my $available_bytes;
        if ($overflow_unread) {
            $available_bytes = $overflow_unread;
        }
        else {
            $available_bytes = pack("L", 0);
            ioctl (STDIN, FIONREAD(), $available_bytes);
            $available_bytes = unpack("L", $available_bytes);
        }

        # will it fit?
        my $remaining_space = $buffer_size_max - $buffer_size;
        my $try_to_read_bytes = $available_bytes;
        if ($try_to_read_bytes > $remaining_space) {
            $try_to_read_bytes = $remaining_space;
        }

        # read input
        if ($try_to_read_bytes > 0) {
            my $input_data;
            my $num_read = read (STDIN, $input_data, $try_to_read_bytes);
            die "read error: $!" unless defined $num_read;
            exit if $num_read == 0;       # EOF
            $buffer{$now} = $input_data;  # save input
            push @timestamps, $now;       # save the timestamp
            $buffer_size += length $input_data;
            if ($overflow_unread) {
                $overflow_unread -= length $input_data;
            }
            elsif (length $input_data < $available_bytes) {
                $overflow_unread = $available_bytes - length $input_data;
            }
        }
    }

    # write + delete any data old enough
    my $then = $now - $delay_usec; # when data is old enough
    while (scalar @timestamps && $timestamps[0] < $then) {
        my $ts = shift @timestamps;
        print $buffer{$ts} if defined $buffer{$ts};
        $buffer_size -= length $buffer{$ts};
        die "Serious problem\n" unless $buffer_size >= 0;
        delete $buffer{$ts};
    }

    # usleep any remaining time up to $time_slice
    my $time_left = (sprintf "%d%06d", gettimeofday) - $now;
    usleep ($time_slice - $time_left) if $time_slice > $time_left;
}
```

*Feel free to post comments and suggestions below!*

Comment: Ah, the same day I implemented it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21078153/1987178 I tested your implementation with my examples (in particular webcam stream delay), it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: I tested `pv` with my program, the throughput is always equal to the buffer size divided by the delay. With the same parameters (3 seconds delay, 10Mb buffer), I have a throughput of 3,33Mb/s: `pv < /dev/zero | delay 3s -b10m > /dev/null`

Comment: @rom1v Yes, I noticed that as well. Not the case with my Perl code though, it's much slower and doesn't depend on the buffer size, at least not if it's reasonably large. On my system it levels out at 639Kb/sec no matter how large the buffer is.

Comment: @romv1 Still, a nice mental exercise. I guess we'll be solving programming quizzes instead of crossword puzzles when we get old :)